# Android ProgressBar ResourceNotFound res/drawable.check_animated.xml only on device Allwinner A88S

Tags: android, android-layout, device, android-resources

I'm trying to display a progress bar. It works on all devices I tested (about 10 devices), but it fails on a low cost device called Allwinner A88S Android 5.1.1. The android version is not the problem as other devices in 5.1.1 works.

So, it fails to find ressource called res/drawable/check_animated.xml
My guess is that maybe it's related with a missing support library, but I can't find which library would provide check_animated.xml. Any clue or idea will be very appreciated. Maybe I could provide my own check_animated.xml, but can't find anywhere this file. Thank you.

Here is how the ProgressBar is described in the layout

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/jdp_waitbar"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:max="100"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/jdp_progress_drawable"
    />
```

And here is the exception :

```
   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/check_animated.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200d3
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2479)
      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:267)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:253)
      at android.widget.ProgressBar.<init>(ProgressBar.java:249)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
      at com.furetcompany.base.components.WaitingView.createView(WaitingView.java:112) 
      at com.furetcompany.base.components.WaitingView.<init>(WaitingView.java:45) 
      at com.furetcompany.base.network.CircuitDownloader.showWaitingDialog(CircuitDownloader.java:86) 
      at com.furetcompany.base.network.CircuitDownloader$5.run(CircuitDownloader.java:221) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Probably seems like the `nativeDecodeAsset()` in `BitmapFactory` is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests, it seems that the problem is with the theme of the activity.

replacing

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

with

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

fixes the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Check the values of
`compileSdkVersion`
`targetSdkVersion`
in your app-level gradle build file and make sure that they are up to date. Also make sure that `minSdkVersion`is equal to or lower than the latest API version supported by the device in which the app is crashing. For Android 5.1.1 your `minSdkVersion` should be 22 or lower. Clean the project and try again.